# Angularjs directive not updating parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm really struggling trying to put a directive working on my form.
I have date-time fields where i need to use plugins in order to keep the old browser compatibility.

This is my html

```
<input ng-model="search.endDate" type="text" date-time-picker value="search.endDate" class="form-control">
```

This is my directive

```
app.directive('dateTimePicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        scope : {
            value : '='
        },
        link : function($scope, element, attrs){
            element.bind('blur', function(){
                $scope.value = element.val();
                    $scope.apply;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**What i'm trying to accomplish :** 
In Parent Scope i have $scope.search.endDate, which stores the date to be sent later on.

I want to use a directive without template, and everytime i change the value on that field the value on parent scope is updated.

**My Problem:**
The code above is working till certain point, where i'm able to select the date and time from the plugin, which translates into **08/25/2016 12:21 PM**, but it appears that $scope.apply only works the first time, meaning that if i go and choose another date-time from the plugin, parent scope variable is no longer updated.

How can i by changing the value on the field propagate the change to parent scope ?

What am i doing wrong ?

**EDIT1:**

```
element.bind('blur', function(){
                $scope.value= element.val();
                $scope.$apply();
            });
```

Comment: Apply is  a function...$scope.$apply() .

Comment: omg, i feel so stupid atm, i lost so many hours trying to find the solution, i've read a bunch of stackoverflow questions . And still all i needed was to call $scope.$apply() instead of $scope.$apply like i was doing.

Answer (score 0):

As ruhul pointed out $apply is a function, so you should call it actually.

However relying on scope variables is not the best way to go. 
Seems like your directive actually depends on the parent directive, so I'd just require the parent's controller with:

```
    restrict : 'AE',
    require  : '^parentDirective',
    scope : {
        value : '='
    }
```

And then you can actually do whatever you need to do without polluting the scope.